# How to tell complex structures apart

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry

Complex structures are rigid, yet weirdly flexible. For example, the Riemannian mapping theorem says that every non-empty simply connected open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ that is not $\mathbb{C}$ is biholomorphically equivalent to the interior of the unit disc. Yet the whole of $\mathbb{C}$ is not. In a similar vein, there seem to be many different complex structures on a 2-torus.

Are there intuitive ways to see the difference between complex structures on the same smooth manifold? My preferred answer would be in terms of "geometric objects/quantities" measured by the complex structures --- in the spirit the Euler characteristic counting holes for a closed Riemann surface.

Comment: As you posed the question it seems to me that an answer should be related to geometric concepts as sheaf of holomorphic functions, cohomology groups, ecc.  As for the example of the interior of the disc and  $\mathbb{C}$ the difference is that the structure sheaf of one of them (the interior of the disc) as non constant global bounded sections but the sheaf for $\mathbb{C}$ have just constant global bounded sections.

Comment: You may want to read about the Riemann moduli space and Teichmüller space for real surfaces: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teichm%C3%BCller_space

Comment: In the sense you ask, the short answer is probably "no". Moduli spaces can be Really Complicated. Even thinking of "well-understood" examples, the product $S^{2} \times S^{2}$ admits countably many inequivalent holomorphic structures (the even Hirzebruch surfaces), as does the non-trivial $S^{2}$ bundle over $S^{2}$ (the odd Hirzebruch surfaces). At the very least, understanding the difference between holomorphic structures on these smooth manifolds entails deformation theory.